# Python How to schedule the parallel scripts for every seconds ? like (cron job)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scripting, multiprocessing, scheduler

Hey everyone i have script that works parallel, i was using `APScheduler` for scheduling the tasks but it works synchron (`BlockingScheduler,BackgroundScheduler`) doesnt work on parallel processes. What would be your advices , how can i run  the parallel processes for every second ? also im using `multiprocesses` for parallel

EDİT:I have just solved it, if anyone gets  trouble like this issue, here the example

```
from multiprocessing import Process

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BlockingScheduler

def work_log_cpu1():
    print(" Proces work_log_cpu1")
    list11=[]
    for i in range(10000000):
        list11.append(i*2)
    print("Proces work_log_cpu1 finished")


def work_log_cpu2():
    print("Proces work_log_cpu2")
    list12=[]
    for i in range(10000000):
        list12.append(i*2)
    print("Proces work_log_cpu2 finished")


def work_log_cpu3():
    print(" Proces work_log_cpu3")
    list13=[]
    for i in range(10000000):
        list13.append(i*2)
    print("Proces work_log_cpu3 finished")
    


def main():
    # sleeps=[3,5,2,7]
    process=Process(target=work_log_cpu1)
    process2=Process(target=work_log_cpu2)
    process3=Process(target=work_log_cpu3)


    process.start()
    process2.start()
    process3.start()

    
    process.join()
    process2.join()
    process3.join()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    # main()
    sched.add_job(main, 'interval', seconds=1,id='first_job',max_instances=1)
    sched.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with multiprocessing?

```
import multiprocessing

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=func1, args=("var1", "var2",))
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=func2, args=("var3", "var4",))
p1.start()
p2.start()
p2.join()
```

Comment: i meant the  cron job , if we go through on your example i wanna repeat the p1 and p2 tasks for  every second. How can i do this ?

Comment: Wrap them in a function, and run this function from "APScheduler"

Comment: I have found the  solution 1 hours ago  like  your suggest, anyway thanks a lot  for response